# can I use whatsapp like gmail with login and password? without everytime scan code?

Tags: web, whatsapp

can I use whats app like gmail with login and password?  without every time scan code?
Because I need whats app some time different computer. so, it is possible to make id and password to use whats app in another computer without scan code?

Comment: No, then Whatsapp would have to reveal that your password is just that IMEI code written on the back of many phones. (Or at least it used to be, can't find any recent info about it.)

Comment: Why is this a question about information security again?